# Mirroring ViewPager swiping with ActionBar Tab Indicator

Tags: android, right-to-left

I'm implementing a RTL layout so I need to mirror ViewPager swiping so when I swipe right the tabs indicator moves left.

I set `viewPager.setCurrentItem(lastitemindex)` which allowed me to page right but in fact it's starting from the last item as expected which is not what I want to achieve.

I want something like the app in the following pics (need more reputation to post pics directly):

[Mobogenie Arabic Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUk2U.png)

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English!

**Please note:** I've `android:supportsRtl="true"` in *AndroidManifest.xml*

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUk2U.png):

Comment: What you describe does not make much sense to me. Why would the animation run opposite of the finger movement, just because of RTL? If you simply want the pages to appear in reverse order, reverse the order of the pages in the `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, sorry I expressed it the wrong way. I've added more information. Please check the question again, thanks!